# extjs looping radiogroup with fieldlabel and boxLabel from database

Tags: loops, extjs

I'm trying to create questionnaire from using radiogroup.
please let me know how to loop the fieldlabel as the questions and boxlabel as the answers that already on database.

Here's the code that I try to loop:

```
 {
                fieldLabel: 'question' +i,
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                items: [
                    {
                        name: 'answer' +i,
                        inputValue: 'A',
                        boxLabel: 'A. ANSWER FOR A' +i,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'answer'+i,
                        inputValue: 'B',
                        boxLabel: 'B. ANSWER FOR B'+i,
                        checked: false,
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use predefined items for radiogroup such as I shown here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/c3h

First you parse your data from DB and define array data for questions, then loop through questions and set answers in inbound loop. Next simply set property **items** of radiogroup to *data*

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm really new on extjs, dont know yet how to parse data for question and answer like u explaine.

Comment: Ok, look at ExtJS Docs how to send Ajax request to your backend and get data in format you need, for ex.: Ext.Ajax